# Mantener texto estático página web(CSS)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Buenas! Tengo una página web con wordpress y tengo un problema con la redimensión del texto. La mejor manera de explicarlo es mostrando dos imágenes. En la primera imagen no tengo ningún problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No obstante, tanto en versión página web como móvil cuando yo cambio la resolución de la pantalla, la parte superior se va redimensionando de una manera que no me gusta dejando lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver, la tabla de abajo se ha quedado tal como estaba, es decir..si me pongo con el cursor hacía la derecha podría verla toda tal como estaba antes. No obstante, la parte superior ha cambiado para poderse adaptar a la pantalla y esto no me interesa!
Seguramente se trata del CSS pero no puedo encontrarlo.

Comment: Lo que quieres es que tu contenido no se adapte a la versión móvil y se quede fijo, ¿verdad? Si es así tendrás que compartir tu fichero css o en su defecto el que esté utilizando el tema de wordpress para poder revisar las @media-query que pueda tener.

Comment: Buenas Hechi. En verdad una cosa que me interesaría es que en la versión móvil se redimensionará haciendo todo mas pequeño pero sin descuadrar el original. No obstante, en la versión web también me está pasando esto y con poder dejarlo estático todo me conformo. El css del tema es demasiado grande, debería poder buscarlo yo y no otra persona pero si alguien ha tenido el mismo problema no voy a morir en el intento jaja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguramente sea alguna media query del css que utiliza la plantilla de wordpress que estés utilizando.

Una `media query` en `CSS` se utiliza, entre otras cosas, para definir reglas de estilos sobre elementos en distintas resoluciones de pantalla.

Abriendo el inspector de elementos del navegador pulsando f12 (yo suelo utilizar chrome), podemos ver una pestaña llamada `styles`, en esta pestaña se muestra a tiempo real las reglas css de la página web. Si redimensionas la ventana podrás ver que en esta pestaña aparecen las media queries que están afectando al sitio web y si te fijas más en detalle también te pone en qué fichero se encuentran y la línea exacta.

Sabiendo esta información no debería suponer ningún problema encontrarlas en el código y modificarlas.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Las tablas no se redimensionan por defecto cuando son más anchas que el ancho del navegador. Para conseguir esto tienes dos opciones: (1) hacer que el scroll sea sólo para la tabla y no para toda la página, o (2) utilizar algún truco de CSS que transforme la estructura de la tabla para que se adapte a los móviles.

[Aquí](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp) tienes un ejemplo de la primera opción, añadiendo el estilo `overflow-x: auto`. Esta es la opción más simple, no estaría adaptada completamente a móviles pero si se ajusta a lo que necesitas sería suficiente. Quedaría algo así:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Y [aquí](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) tienes un ejemplo de la segunda opción, haciendo algunos trucos de CSS. En la página lo explican bastante bien. Lo malo es que es bastante más complicado que la primera opción y puede considerarse que el código es algo sucio pero, en mi opinión, el resultado en móviles es bastante mejor.